# Why is tmux session not shown in who command?

Tags: ssh, debian, tmux

When on Debian I access via ssh and then open a new tmux session, detach it, I see them in the `who` command. Note: In both examples are 2 SSH connections to each server. Ubuntu is Ubuntu Server 20.04.

```
who
debian   pts/0        2021-03-27 23:18 (192.168.178.5)
debian   pts/1        2021-03-27 23:23 (192.168.178.5)
debian   pts/2        2021-03-27 23:27 (tmux(4298).%0)
debian   pts/6        2021-03-27 23:47 (tmux(4298).%4)
```

```
tmux list-sessions
0: 1 windows (created Sat Mar 27 23:27:35 2021) [166x54]
4: 1 windows (created Sat Mar 27 23:47:36 2021) [166x54]
```

On Ubuntu:

```
who
ubuntu     pts/0        2021-03-31 00:01 (192.168.178.5)
ubuntu     pts/2        2021-03-31 00:43 (192.168.178.5)
```

```
tmux list-sessions
0: 1 windows (created Tue Mar 30 18:01:15 2021)
1: 1 windows (created Tue Mar 30 18:29:29 2021)
2: 1 windows (created Tue Mar 30 18:51:09 2021)
3: 1 windows (created Tue Mar 30 19:18:59 2021)
4: 1 windows (created Tue Mar 30 19:20:08 2021)
5: 1 windows (created Tue Mar 30 19:20:38 2021)
```

Comment: Just curious if you can explain the problem you are trying to solve there might be other ways of solving it without `who`.

Comment: It's no real problem. I'm just a curious person and want to learn.

Comment: Is your tmux configured to launch a regular non-login shell or a login shell (iirc the default)?

Comment: I am also interested in this. For me it is a real problem, because on Ubuntu 20.04, `unattended-upgrades` reboots the machine automatically even if there are still running tmux sessions (because `who` does not show them), whereas on Ubuntu 18.04 the behavior is the same as you said on Debian and `unattended-upgrades` does not kill tmux sessions.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20.04.2, both `who` and `pinky` returns the full list of logins, including tmux shells. However, it should be noted that I've upgraded to tmux 3.1c, so maybe you should try [upgrading as well](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/tmux_3.1c-1_amd64.deb.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unintended behavior and a bug in Ubuntu 20.04, which is not present in other Ubuntu versions (not even Ubuntu 20.10). The bug report is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tmux/+bug/1890406

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to the latest tmux version - this works for me, and all dependencies are OK.

For x86/64:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tmux/tmux_3.1c-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./tmux_3.1c-1_amd64.deb
```

For arm64:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tmux/tmux_3.1c-1_arm64.deb
sudo apt install ./tmux_3.1c-1_arm64.deb
```

Comment: Note that if you use this way for updating `tmux`, you won't get any `tmux` updates anymore from Ubuntu (until Ubuntu ships a version newer than 3.1c). This means one needs to watch `tmux` manually for important (security) updates.

Comment: Of course that's a tradeoff you need to take into account - however, all the latest tmux updates for Ubuntu have been Debian updates anyway, so I'd say there is a very little risk this would happen. Anyway, for me it's a valid solution.